# Presence Indicator next to Outlook Contact Item

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am building a custom addin for Outlook at would like to show a colored indicator (cirlce) next to a contacts name showing whether they are at their desk, in a meeting etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is not clear where exactly in the UI you need to add an indicator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSTO (nor Outlook) doesn't provide anything for that. The best what you can do is to develop a custom task pane or Outlook form region, see [Create Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2019) for more information.

You may also consider developing an IM integration, see [Integrating IM applications with Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/integrating-im-applications-with-office).

Comment: Thanks I will go with a form region :-)